# How to remove/disable accuracy circle from current location in Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want remove that blue accuracy circle from my current location in Android Google Maps v2.

I found way with removing circle and marker, and puting new marker, but it seems to me uncool.
I search way to disable only that circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove it from stock Android Google Map app (that's obvious for you I hope).

You can however do what you want in your own app, i.e.:

1. [don't show my-location layer](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29)
2. and if you want to show my-location just add your custom marker in [`getLastLocation` position](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#getLastLocation%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient%29)